# Set score for each correct option

Tags: reactjs

I am doing quiz app and I need to make the last step but I do not know how. I have array where all data contains, and there is correct option for each array. In the function I compare if index of button is equal to correct option and if button is not clicked, I add 1 point. But when I try to click to the second question I can not, because in first I set click:false. 
What I need to do that if I clicked to button from question I can not click it one more time, but in other question button I can. Help me please. 
I will make in quiz 10 question so I do not want to make state for each question and I do not want to use disable function in button.
Code:

```js
class Quiz extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = 
      {
      questions: [{title: "Question-1", answers:['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    correct:2}, {title: "Question-2", answers:['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    correct:0}], 
    numbers: [0, 1, 2],
    progress:0,
    score:0,
      click: true
    }
    
    this.checkAnswer = this.checkAnswer.bind(this);
    
  }
  
  checkAnswer(correct, index) {
    var newScore = 0;
    if (correct === index && this.state.click) {
      newScore = this.state.score+1;
      this.setState({score: newScore, click: false});
    }
  }
            
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {
          this.state.questions.map(({title, answers, correct}, i) => (
            <div key={i} className="card">
              <div className="card-body">
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                {answers.map((answers, j) => 
                 <button key={j} onClick={ () => {
                  this.checkAnswer(correct, j);
                     }}>{answers}</button>
                 )}
              </div>
            </div>
          ))
        }
        <p>{this.state.score}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



const Root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Quiz />, Root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very determined. Which question regarding the same problem is it? Fifth?

Just add info to each question if it was correctly answered.

Here you go:

```js
class Quiz extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = 
      {
      questions: [{title: "Question-1", answers:['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    correct:2}, {title: "Question-2", answers:['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    correct:0}], 
    numbers: [0, 1, 2],
    progress:0,
    score:0
    }
    
    this.checkAnswer = this.checkAnswer.bind(this);
    
  }
  
  checkAnswer(q, i) {
    if (q.correct === i && !q.answered) {
      q.answered = true;
      this.setState({score: this.state.score + 1});
    }
  }
            
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {
          this.state.questions.map((q, i) => (
            <div key={i} className="card">
              <div className="card-body">
                <h1>{q.title}</h1>
                {q.answers.map((answer, j) => 
                 <button key={j} onClick={ () => {
                  this.checkAnswer(q, j);
                     }}>{answer}</button>
                 )}
              </div>
            </div>
          ))
        }
        <p>{this.state.score}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



const Root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Quiz />, Root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Then obviously cllick option should be a part of question, not common for whole state, then you can do like this

```
this.state.questions.map(({title, answers, click, correct}, i) => (
            <div key={i} className="card">
              <div className="card-body">
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                {answers.map((answers, j) => 
                 <button key={j} onClick={ () => {
                  click && this.checkAnswer(correct, j);
                     }}>{answers}</button>
                 )}
```